# How to recognize the source topic in the dead letter queue messages if multiple topics are pushing the unack msg in the same dead letter queue GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, dead-letter

How to recognize the source topic in the dead letter queue messages if there are multiple topics pushing the unack messages in the same  the same dead letter queue

Comment: I think you can't.

Comment: Do the unacknowledged messages go into the dead letter topic or only the negative ack once are forwarded? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: All the negative ack messages: as well the timeout error (unack) as the explicit nack. The message are sent to the dead letter topic only after 5 or more negative ack.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same but in my case, even when it's limited to 5 retries, it keeps on retrying the messages endlessly, only if I do explicit nack(), the messages get retried for 5 times and are getting used to dead letter topic, can you please suggest a way to fix this or if I am missing something. @guillaumeblaquiere